# read output failed only read the last output

Tags: java, android, arraylist, chatbot

I have this situation where the chabot can reply three times but only the only reply he can read is the lastone. Is there a way to read those three message?

```
 private void receiveMessage(String sendText) {

    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face_2);
    smusic = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.what);

    //Receive message
    final Message receivedMessage = new Message.Builder()
            .setUser(mUsers.get(1))
            .setRight(false)
            .hideIcon(true)
            .setText(ChatBot.INSTANCE.talk(mUsers.get(0).getName(), sendText))
    .build();


    if (sendText.equals("1")|| sendText.equals("2")){
        int [] rcv = new int[1];
        for (int i =0; i<rcv.length;i++) {
            receivedMessage.setText("What? ");
            receivedMessage.setText("1 What is it?");
            receivedMessage.setText("2 Oh hey Mach!");
            smusic.start();
        }
    }
if (mReplyDelay < 0) {
        mReplyDelay = (new Random().nextInt(3) + 1) * 1000;
    }
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mChatView.receive(receivedMessage);
            //Add message list
            mMessageList.add(receivedMessage);

        }
    }, mReplyDelay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are overriding the receivedMessage .
When you do this, it will override and only the last message will be set and sent.

```
for (int i =0; i<rcv.length;i++) {
    receivedMessage.setText("What? ");
    receivedMessage.setText("1 What is it?");
    receivedMessage.setText("2 Oh hey Mach!");
    smusic.start();
}
```

So if you want all 3 message, instead of doing above step, you can append in string seperated by \n and set text in receivedMessage.

To append in string seperated by \n

```
String.join("\n", "text");
```

Or otherwise after setting text in recieve message, read the output before next setting the text in recieve message.

Comment: Solved or want any other solution ?